# Elisp best way to concatenate lists of predicates

Tags: emacs, append

What is the best way to  merge predicates like these into one predicate

```
'(("first" . font-lock-function-name-face))
'(("second" . font-lock-constant-face))
```

So that the answer would be:

```
'(("first" . font-lock-function-name-face)
("second" . font-lock-constant-face))
```

Comment: Those are not predicates, BTW. They are just lists (of a single cons each), and the result is a single list (of two conses). Some code might make use of such a list to realize the behavior of a predicate somehow, but on their own they are just lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
(append '(("first" . font-lock-function-name-face)) '(("second" . font-lock-constant-face)))
```